# putting space between integer and '/' using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, linux, numbers, space

I have a String `S= "grep -iRl 2020062312213461801003087/var/seamless/spool/tdr/Reconciliation"`
and i want to add space between last number and `"/"`

like i want my output to be `grep -iRl 2020062312213461801003087 /var/seamless/spool/tdr/Reconciliation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String S= "grep -iRl 2020062312213461801003087/var/seamless/spool/tdr/Reconciliation";
String replaced = S.replaceAll("(\\d)(/)", "$1 $2");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

result:

```
grep -iRl 2020062312213461801003087 /var/seamless/spool/tdr/Reconciliation
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find index of first "/" by *yourstring.indexOf("/");* . and insert char to string by *yourString.insert(index of "/", " ");*.
your code will be like that
`

```
int index = yourString.indexOf("/");
yourString.insert(index, " ");
```